# Why judaism.stackexchange.com? How come not yahadut.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, hebrew

Why is our site named [***judaism***.stackexchange.com](http://judaism.stackexchange.com)?  How come not [***yahadut***.stackexchange.com](http://yahadut.stackexchange.com)? Our StackExchange website is about Judaism.  But we are Jews, so we should call it Yahadut.  For whatever reason (perhaps because they are proud of their heritage), Muslims call their religion Islam and not [Mohammedanism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mohammedanism), which is not part of the Arabic language.  Why has the American Jewish establishment eschewed the Hebrew-language term *Yahadut* by choosing the term *Judaism* as the "official name" of our religion, especially when in this day and age we are supposedly always ever so eager to use the Hebrew language (because so many Jews now live in Israel and speak the Hebrew tongue)?  IMHO, we should have more pride in our culture than members of other religions have in theirs.  Kind of like *Kinat Sofrim*. The official name of this website is **Mi.Yodeya**, but why not change the website URL from ***judaism***.etc. into ***yahadut***.etc.?

For more of what seems to make sense to me, please take a look at [this comment](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/why-judaism-stackexchange-com-how-come-not-yahadut-stackexchange-com#comment3126_1198) of mine. (open it in a new tab or just read the quote below)

> we don't use English here. We say shabbat and not sabbath, tefillin and not phylacteries. Believe it or not, but these words are not English.

Comment: Note that http://yodeya.stackexchange.com redirects (and did so even before graduation and, I *think*, before migration).

Comment: @msh210 - Btw, where was the pre-migration site hosted?

Comment: @msh210 and Adam, I set up the original mi.yodeya as yodeya.stackexchange.com (my choice of subdomain) on the Stack Exchange 1.0 platform, which was hosted by the same people, but with a different (now dropped) business model, wherein anyone could set up a site and run it as they please, but they'd eventually have to pay for the privilege. When that site was migrated into J.SE, the yodeya.stackexchange.com subdomain was redirected to point to judaism.stackexchange.com instead of to the SE 1.0 site.

Comment: Why Yahadut? Why not Yahadus? Or Yiddishkeit? Or how about Ivrius/Ivriut? Why don't we conduct all the Q&A on this site in Lashon HaKodesh?

Comment: @HodofHod More like 'ivriyuth if we really want to go there :)

Comment: @DoubleAA Not particularly. I was never one for _precise_ transliteration, and I'm the type that if I ever did go for that, I'd probably use the [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

Comment: @DoubleAA - I agree with [AviD's comment](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-common-way-to-type-in-hebrew-for-this-site?rq=1#comment29_13) in regards to what you are asking. (click on link)

Comment: @HodofHod - I agree with you (although you seem a bit peculiarly sarcastic by making that comment), but let's take this one step at a time. Nobody disagrees that **Hebrew is the national language of Klal Yisrael**. Not Yiddish.  And not Yinglish or Yeshivish. Let Klal Yisrael unite once and for all.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I wasn't asking; I was telling.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I apologize, in retrospect I realize my comment came off as very sarcastic. But I meant it seriously: why "Yahadut"? As far as I know, it's not used in Tanach, and conjugating "Yehudi" to "Yahadut" is not much more Jewish than conjugating "Ivri" to "Ivriut", so why one over the other? Additionally, I don't know if you are distinguishing Hebrew from Lashon HaKodesh, but assuming that you are not: why should the title of the site be in Hebrew, but not the rest of the site? I mean that seriously.

Comment: @HodofHod Just FYI I'm seeing Yahadut referring to "Judaism" in the writings of rishonim (particularly Ashkenazi ones right now) so it's at least a relatively traditional term to use.

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course. But were they Ashkenazim? Maybe they meant "Yahadus"? ;)

Comment: @HodofHod I wonder. I doubt the soft 'th' was lost before Rashi. Maybe I'll ask.

Comment: @HodofHod - Yes, different conjugations, declensions, combinations, and permutations of words that are in lashon ha-kodesh are still considered lashon ha-kodesh. That means Hebrew and things such as Yahadut, etc.

Comment: So Lashon HaKodesh is now determined by the Vaad Halashon?

Comment: @HodofHod (A common straw-man, but) No, but I would argue that it's determined by the people. So long as the people accept their words they join the language. (Note that the people don't always accept their rules. There are lots of famous examples of words that no one uses, like שח-רחוק for טלפון)

Comment: @DoubleAA 1) Straw men are by definition (AFAIK) intentional; this one wasn't. 2) What do you gain by saying it's the people, and not the Vaad? So Lashon HaKodesh is a language built on social consensus, just like any other? Hm, sounds like a good question to ask.

Comment: @HodofHod 1) I wasn't trying to say that you did it malevelontly; in fact, you might not have ever thought about it that way; but I do think it is that form of [logical fallacy](http://www.enwp.org/Straw_man). 2) I think that is very reasonable. It's no secret that Hebrew language patterns have changed from Bereishit to Divrei HaYamim to the Mishna to the Rishonim. (Note that pronunciation of letters may be different and talui on mesora although that too is debatable. This refers only to words, syntax etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Hmm, but exactly how much? How much can people add/take away from it before it stops being the Holy Language? Question time! Further discussion will be happening in chat (at least, mine will).

Comment: @HodofHod http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus

Comment: @IsaacMoses +1 I was thinking just that!

Comment: @DoubleAA, do you read http://adderabbi.blogspot.com ? That's where I've heard of this concept.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Only when linked to it. Embarrassingly enough, I learned about that boat from browsing wikipedia :-) The concept behind it though I think most people realize at some point in their lives even if they don't formalize it. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox

Comment: related: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/219 - If we want to attract Israeli Talmidei Chachamim to our site?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, If you want to propose making Hebrew either the main language of discourse here (very unlikely) or an acceptable language of discourse (certainly worthy of discussion), that'd be a different question.

Comment: @HodofHod FWIW the Vaad HaLashon decided that Modern Hebrew should include the Mizrahi forms of ח ע ק ט ו as distinct from כ א כ ת ב (generally considered by all to be the originals). Moral of the story: the Vaad has no actual power and the language developed organically from many new immigrants who had trouble with gutturals showing up to a place with a Mizrahi bent. Again the blame on the Vaad is but a straw-man. Really Charedim don't like Modern Hebrew just bc the secular Zionists were proud of it.

Answer (score 7):

The common language of discourse on this site in particular and on Stack Exchange in general is English. The following subdomain names are all consistent with this pattern:

- Judaism
- Islam
- German
- French
- Japanese
- Chinese
- Spanish

Comment: Chinese.SE has a lot of foreign characters all over, just go to their page and see for yourself.  But we don't use English here.  We say shabbat and not sabbath, tefillin and not phylacteries.  Believe it or not, but these words are not English.

Comment: @AdamMosheh 1) You've reinforced my point that the subdomain choice convention is consistent across the network. 2) Your comment contains two non-English words, out of ~50. Your question contains ten, out of ~200. Your most recent question on Mi Yodeya contains 8, out of ~180. "We don't use English here" is demonstrably incorrect. 3) I have [advocated](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52/should-we-have-a-jargon-policy-guideline), and many have implemented, mitigation and limitation of the use of non-English jargon here, for accessibility's sake.

Comment: No, not [French.SE](http://french.stackexchange.com/). - Also, look at [this](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/219). And [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1372).

Comment: @AdamMosheh, Oh, that's interesting. But you've only strengthened my point with respect to subdomains. francais.stackexchange.com doesn't even exist as an alternate.

Comment: @IsaacMoses But apparently [deutsch.stackexchange.com](http://deutsch.stackexchange.com) does.

Answer (score 4):

The answer most fundamentally is that we don't control the domain. That's Stack Exchange, Inc.'s responsibility. We just use their technology.

If they ever would decide to let us choose (which I highly doubt), I would still pick Judaism as it means exactly the same thing as all the other suggestions, but in a way that more people can understand. If I can say [Keriat Shema](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%96_%D7%90) in English, I would hope English is at least good enough to name a website.

Comment: You can say it Keriat Shema in English, but Rabbi (Judah the Prince?) from Brachot 13a tells us that is incorrect.

Comment: @AdamMosheh That's your excuse to downvote this? LOL! (I mean that literally!). Anyway, it's a good thing we don't rule like him, but rather like the Chachamim quoted there that it is permissible. I don't see why you would downvote because I ruled like EVERYONE post-gemara.

Comment: Chachamim? Don't you mean the Sages?

Comment: @AdamMosheh They mean the same thing.